# How to remove blank area between sizers in wxPython

Tags: python, wxpython

Is there anything wrong with my code? I used 3 sizers in 1 boxsizer in main frame. The bottom sizer is used for plotting and the other two are used for user interaction. The most important problem lies in too much blank area exists between 3 sizers now. I want my GUI looks more compact and the plot area should be largers if possible.

```
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*- 

###########################################################################
## Python code generated with wxFormBuilder (version Oct  8 2012)
## http://www.wxformbuilder.org/
##
## PLEASE DO "NOT" EDIT THIS FILE!
###########################################################################

import os
import wx
import wx.xrc
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('WXAgg')
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_wxagg import \
    FigureCanvasWxAgg as FigureCanvas, \
    NavigationToolbar2WxAgg as NavigationToolbar
#from numpy import arange, sin, pi

###########################################################################
## Class MainFrame
###########################################################################

class MainFrame ( wx.Frame ):

    def __init__( self, parent ):
        wx.Frame.__init__ ( self, parent, id = wx.ID_ANY, title = u"计算机插值 v0.1", pos = wx.DefaultPosition, size = wx.Size( 508,530 ), style = wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE|wx.FRAME_SHAPED|wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL )

        self.SetSizeHintsSz( wx.DefaultSize, wx.DefaultSize )
        self.SetForegroundColour( wx.SystemSettings.GetColour( wx.SYS_COLOUR_3DLIGHT ) )

        ####################################################################
        self.MainMenu = wx.MenuBar( 0 )
        self.File = wx.Menu()
        self.SaveAs = wx.MenuItem( self.File, wx.ID_ANY, u"另存为...", wx.EmptyString, wx.ITEM_NORMAL )
        self.File.AppendItem( self.SaveAs )

        self.Exit = wx.MenuItem( self.File, wx.ID_ANY, u"退出...", wx.EmptyString, wx.ITEM_NORMAL )
        self.File.AppendItem( self.Exit )

        self.MainMenu.Append( self.File, u"文件" ) 

        self.About_M = wx.Menu()
        self.About = wx.MenuItem( self.About_M, wx.ID_ANY, u"关于", wx.EmptyString, wx.ITEM_NORMAL )
        self.About_M.AppendItem( self.About )

        self.MainMenu.Append( self.About_M, u"关于" ) 

        self.SetMenuBar( self.MainMenu )

        ####################################################################        
        MainSizer = wx.BoxSizer( wx.VERTICAL )

        self.MainPanel = wx.Panel( self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL )
        UserSizer = wx.BoxSizer( wx.VERTICAL )

        upperSizer = wx.BoxSizer( wx.HORIZONTAL )
        ####################################################################

        self.TextExplanation = wx.StaticText( self.MainPanel, wx.ID_ANY, u"请在下面输入框内输入要插值的数，以空格间隔。\n输入范围在(1.2, 2.0)。", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
        self.TextExplanation.Wrap( -1 )
        upperSizer.Add( self.TextExplanation, 0, wx.ALL, 20 )


        upperSizer.AddSpacer( ( 0, 0), 1, wx.EXPAND, 5 )

        RadioBoxInterpolationChoices = [ u"线性插值", u"抛物线插值" ]
        self.RadioBoxInterpolation = wx.RadioBox( self.MainPanel, wx.ID_ANY, u"插值种类", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, RadioBoxInterpolationChoices, 1, wx.RA_SPECIFY_COLS )
        self.RadioBoxInterpolation.SetSelection( 1 )
        upperSizer.Add( self.RadioBoxInterpolation, 0, wx.ALL, 5 )


        UserSizer.Add( upperSizer, 1, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND|wx.SHAPED, 5 )

        lowerSizer = wx.BoxSizer( wx.HORIZONTAL )

        self.TextCtrVal = wx.TextCtrl( self.MainPanel, wx.ID_ANY, wx.EmptyString, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, wx.TE_PROCESS_ENTER )
        lowerSizer.Add( self.TextCtrVal, 0, wx.ALL, 20 )


        lowerSizer.AddSpacer( ( 0, 0), 1, wx.EXPAND, 5 )

        self.ButtonCal = wx.Button( self.MainPanel, wx.ID_ANY, u"计算", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
        lowerSizer.Add( self.ButtonCal, 0, wx.ALL, 20 )

        self.ButtonCls = wx.Button( self.MainPanel, wx.ID_ANY, u"清空", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
        lowerSizer.Add( self.ButtonCls, 0, wx.ALL, 20 )


        UserSizer.Add( lowerSizer, 1, wx.EXPAND|wx.SHAPED, 5 )

        PlotSizer = wx.BoxSizer( wx.VERTICAL )

        #################################################
        p1 = PlotPanel(self)
        PlotSizer.Add(p1, 1, wx.EXPAND |wx.ALL,1)

        #################################################    
        UserSizer.Add( PlotSizer, 1, wx.EXPAND, 5 )


        self.MainPanel.SetSizer( UserSizer )
        self.MainPanel.Layout()
        UserSizer.Fit( self.MainPanel )
        MainSizer.Add( self.MainPanel, 1, wx.EXPAND |wx.ALL, 1 )


        self.SetSizer( MainSizer )
        self.Layout()

        self.Centre( wx.BOTH )

        # Connect Events
        self.Bind( wx.EVT_MENU, self.SaveAsFile, id = self.SaveAs.GetId() )
        self.Bind( wx.EVT_MENU, self.ExitNow, id = self.Exit.GetId() )
        self.Bind( wx.EVT_MENU, self.Dialog, id = self.About.GetId() )
        self.TextCtrVal.Bind( wx.EVT_TEXT_ENTER, self.Calculate )
        self.ButtonCal.Bind( wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.Calcualte )
        self.ButtonCls.Bind( wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.ClearPlot )

        # Necessary varibles
        selection = self.RadioBoxInterpolation.GetSelection()       

    def __del__( self ):
        pass

    # Virtual event handlers, overide them in your derived class
    def SaveAsFile( self, event ):
        event.Skip()

    def ExitNow( self, event ):
        self.Close(True) 

    def Dialog( self, event ):
        dlg = wx.MessageDialog( self, u"Test", u"Test", wx.OK)
        dlg.ShowModal() 
        dlg.Destroy() 

    def Calculate( self, event ):
        event.Skip()

    def Calcualte( self, event ):
        event.Skip()

    def ClearPlot( self, event ):
        event.Skip()

###########################################################################
## Class PlotPanel
###########################################################################

class PlotPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self,parent, -1,size=(300,530))
        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.figure = matplotlib.figure.Figure(figsize=(5,4))
        self.axes = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
        self.y_max = 2.0
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self,-1,self.figure)

        self.sizer.Add(self.canvas,proportion =1, border = 5,flag = wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetSizer(self.sizer)

if __name__ == '__main__': 
    app = wx.PySimpleApp()
    app.frame = MainFrame(None)
    app.frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed two lines of code, and think it might be what you are looking for.

```
UserSizer.Add( upperSizer, 0, wx.EXPAND, 5 )
```

and

```
UserSizer.Add( lowerSizer, 0, 0, 5 )
```

Here is the updated code:

```
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

###########################################################################
## Python code generated with wxFormBuilder (version Oct  8 2012)
## http://www.wxformbuilder.org/
##
## PLEASE DO "NOT" EDIT THIS FILE!
###########################################################################

import os
import wx
import wx.xrc
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('WXAgg')
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_wxagg import \
    FigureCanvasWxAgg as FigureCanvas, \
    NavigationToolbar2WxAgg as NavigationToolbar
#from numpy import arange, sin, pi

###########################################################################
## Class MainFrame
###########################################################################

class MainFrame ( wx.Frame ):

    def __init__( self, parent ):
        wx.Frame.__init__ ( self, parent, id = wx.ID_ANY, title = u"计算机插值 v0.1", pos = wx.DefaultPosition, size = wx.Size( 508,530 ), style = wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE|wx.FRAME_SHAPED|wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL )

        self.SetSizeHintsSz( wx.DefaultSize, wx.DefaultSize )
        self.SetForegroundColour( wx.SystemSettings.GetColour( wx.SYS_COLOUR_3DLIGHT ) )

        ####################################################################
        self.MainMenu = wx.MenuBar( 0 )
        self.File = wx.Menu()
        self.SaveAs = wx.MenuItem( self.File, wx.ID_ANY, u"另存为...", wx.EmptyString, wx.ITEM_NORMAL )
        self.File.AppendItem( self.SaveAs )

        self.Exit = wx.MenuItem( self.File, wx.ID_ANY, u"退出...", wx.EmptyString, wx.ITEM_NORMAL )
        self.File.AppendItem( self.Exit )

        self.MainMenu.Append( self.File, u"文件" )

        self.About_M = wx.Menu()
        self.About = wx.MenuItem( self.About_M, wx.ID_ANY, u"关于", wx.EmptyString, wx.ITEM_NORMAL )
        self.About_M.AppendItem( self.About )

        self.MainMenu.Append( self.About_M, u"关于" )

        self.SetMenuBar( self.MainMenu )

        ####################################################################
        MainSizer = wx.BoxSizer( wx.VERTICAL )

        self.MainPanel = wx.Panel( self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL )
        UserSizer = wx.BoxSizer( wx.VERTICAL )

        upperSizer = wx.BoxSizer( wx.HORIZONTAL )
        ####################################################################

        self.TextExplanation = wx.StaticText( self.MainPanel, wx.ID_ANY, u"请在下面输入框内输入要插值的数，以空格间隔。\n输入范围在(1.2, 2.0)。", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
        self.TextExplanation.Wrap( -1 )
        upperSizer.Add( self.TextExplanation, 0, wx.ALL, 20 )


        upperSizer.AddSpacer( ( 0, 0), 1, wx.EXPAND, 5 )

        RadioBoxInterpolationChoices = [ u"线性插值", u"抛物线插值" ]
        self.RadioBoxInterpolation = wx.RadioBox( self.MainPanel, wx.ID_ANY, u"插值种类", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, RadioBoxInterpolationChoices, 1, wx.RA_SPECIFY_COLS )
        self.RadioBoxInterpolation.SetSelection( 1 )
        upperSizer.Add( self.RadioBoxInterpolation, 0, wx.ALL, 5 )


        UserSizer.Add( upperSizer, 0, wx.EXPAND, 5 )

        lowerSizer = wx.BoxSizer( wx.HORIZONTAL )

        self.TextCtrVal = wx.TextCtrl( self.MainPanel, wx.ID_ANY, wx.EmptyString, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, wx.TE_PROCESS_ENTER )
        lowerSizer.Add( self.TextCtrVal, 0, wx.ALL, 20 )


        lowerSizer.AddSpacer( ( 0, 0), 1, wx.EXPAND, 5 )

        self.ButtonCal = wx.Button( self.MainPanel, wx.ID_ANY, u"计算", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
        lowerSizer.Add( self.ButtonCal, 0, wx.ALL, 20 )

        self.ButtonCls = wx.Button( self.MainPanel, wx.ID_ANY, u"清空", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
        lowerSizer.Add( self.ButtonCls, 0, wx.ALL, 20 )


        UserSizer.Add( lowerSizer, 0, 0, 5 )

        PlotSizer = wx.BoxSizer( wx.VERTICAL )

        #################################################
        p1 = PlotPanel(self)
        PlotSizer.Add(p1, 1, wx.EXPAND |wx.ALL,1)

        #################################################
        UserSizer.Add( PlotSizer, 1, wx.EXPAND, 5 )


        self.MainPanel.SetSizer( UserSizer )
        self.MainPanel.Layout()
        UserSizer.Fit( self.MainPanel )
        MainSizer.Add( self.MainPanel, 1, wx.EXPAND |wx.ALL, 1 )


        self.SetSizer( MainSizer )
        self.Layout()

        self.Centre( wx.BOTH )

        # Connect Events
        self.Bind( wx.EVT_MENU, self.SaveAsFile, id = self.SaveAs.GetId() )
        self.Bind( wx.EVT_MENU, self.ExitNow, id = self.Exit.GetId() )
        self.Bind( wx.EVT_MENU, self.Dialog, id = self.About.GetId() )
        self.TextCtrVal.Bind( wx.EVT_TEXT_ENTER, self.Calculate )
        self.ButtonCal.Bind( wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.Calcualte )
        self.ButtonCls.Bind( wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.ClearPlot )

        # Necessary varibles
        selection = self.RadioBoxInterpolation.GetSelection()

    def __del__( self ):
        pass

    # Virtual event handlers, overide them in your derived class
    def SaveAsFile( self, event ):
        event.Skip()

    def ExitNow( self, event ):
        self.Close(True)

    def Dialog( self, event ):
        dlg = wx.MessageDialog( self, u"Test", u"Test", wx.OK)
        dlg.ShowModal()
        dlg.Destroy()

    def Calculate( self, event ):
        event.Skip()

    def Calcualte( self, event ):
        event.Skip()

    def ClearPlot( self, event ):
        event.Skip()

###########################################################################
## Class PlotPanel
###########################################################################

class PlotPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self,parent, -1,size=(300,530))
        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.figure = matplotlib.figure.Figure(figsize=(5,4))
        self.axes = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
        self.y_max = 2.0
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self,-1,self.figure)

        self.sizer.Add(self.canvas,proportion =1, border = 5,flag = wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetSizer(self.sizer)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.PySimpleApp()
    app.frame = MainFrame(None)
    app.frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```